# An Inequality of the Square Sum of Random Variable

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

I am facing proving an inequality.

> Given two triples of random variables $(X_1^a,X_2^a,Y^a)$ and $(X_1^b,X_2^b,Y^b)$. These two triples of random variables have the same support set, (i.e. $\forall\ P_{X_1^a,X_2^a,Y^a}(x_1,x_2,y)\neq0,P_{X_1^b,X_2^b,Y^b}(x_1,x_2,y)\neq0$ and vise versa). How to prove the inequality below:
> $$ \sum_{(x_1,x_2,y)}P_{X_1^b,X_2^b,Y^b}(x_1,x_2,y)(\frac{P_{X_1^a,Y^a}(x_1,y)}{P_{X_1^b,Y^b}(x_1,y)}+\frac{P_{X_2^a,Y^a}(x_2,y)}{P_{X_2^b,Y^b}(x_2,y)})^2 \\< \sum_{(x_1,x_2,y)}P_{X_1^b,X_2^b,Y^b}(x_1,x_2,y)(\frac{P_{X_1^a,X_2^a,Y^a}(x_1,x_2,y)}{P_{X_1^b,X_2^b,Y^b}(x_1,x_2,y)}+\frac{P_{Y^a}(y)}{P_{Y^b}(y)})^2$$

I will really appreciate it if anyone can help.

Thank you!